# Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type in go

Tags: http, go

I'm new to GO and I want to make a back-end server with it. I've done a function that removes the `.html` from the URL, here's the code:

```
http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // hack, if requested url is / then point towards /index
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        r.URL.Path = "/index"
    }

    requestedPath := strings.TrimLeft(filepath.Clean(r.URL.Path), "/")
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s.html", "./web-files", requestedPath)
    http.ServeFile(w, r, filename)
}))

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

At first, the code was OK, but went I tried to create a `styles.css` file and link it to the HTML file I got the following error at the console:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: I think you need to include a `Content-Type` header with the value `text/css` on the response: `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css")` before the call to `http.ServeFile(...)`

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I've tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Does the error still complain about "text/plain" or did it properly reflect the change to "text/css"?

Comment: Please include the actual code that is producing an error, all we can currently see is the code for serving html files.

Comment: Duplicate of MIME TYPE in MUX  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105545/mime-type-error-when-applying-css-files-with-go-gorilla-mux-server

Comment: The filename passed to ServeFile is `./web-files/styles.css.html`.  ServeFile returns an error response because there is no such file.   The browser refuses to load the text/plain error response as a CSS file. Use [FileServer](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer) to fix the path computation.  You will also fix the path traversal vulnerability by using FileServer.